# Manually trigger ngx-bootstrap modal via TemplateRef

Tags: bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I would liketo trigger a modal dynamically via typescript. I know this should be easy, so I'm probably looking over something.

**Somewhere in Template:**

`<ng-template #adminmodal>.....Some content right here......</ng-template>`

**Component:**

Trying to make a TemplateRef from the #adminmodal

`@ViewChild('adminmodal', { read: TemplateRef }) _adminModalRef: TemplateRef<any>;`

Trying to trigger and failing miserably

`this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this._adminModalRef);`

It opens a modal, but with an empty modal-content, so there is something wrong with my approach.

Comment: When I refer to 'opens a modal', I mean that the backdrop of the modal is activated. But obvisouly no modal because the modal template is not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach should work, maybe there is a bug inside ngx-boostrap ([https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+modal](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20modal))

Another way according to the docs you could try is via the modalDirective

**Template**

```
<div class="modal fade" bsModal #modal="bs-modal">...</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
  @ViewChild(ModalDirective) modal: ModalDirective;

  showModal() {
    this.modal.show();
  }
```

Hope this helps you out, good luck!